# Problems with Kubernetes Client & Server Versions

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, docker-desktop

I've been using **Docker Desktop for Windows** for a while and recently I updated to the latest version (*3.5.1*) but now I'm having problems with Kubernetes because it updated the **client version** (*1.21.2*) but the **server version** was not updated and continues on the version (*1.19.7*).

How can I update the server version to avoid the conflicts that K8s faces when the versions between client and server are more than 1 version different?

Comment: Hello @Alejandro, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I decided to install Minikube and all problems were solved. Thanks

Comment: Please, post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Hey, @Alejandro -- I've used minikube and others, and none of them are really bad, but I think K3D is the best of the lot. You might want to have a look before you get too deep in minikube.

Comment: @software-engineer I read something about K3D and K3s, and I think it is a good option to study. I want to read the documentation to try to use it. Thanks for the tip/advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Alejandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16385330/alejandro) has mentioned in the comment:

> I decided to install Minikube and all problems were solved.

This problem can also be resolved by reinstalling Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

To try to solve this problem I decided to install Minikube, after that, all those problems were solved. Thanks everyone